# Is this use of Create() right in an Entity Framework context?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When creating an object that will be persisted to the database, and using the `Create()` method for this purpose, do the following snippets do the same?

Snippet 1:

```
Client client = new Client();
client.Name = "Jonh Doe";
database.Clients.Add(client);
database.SaveChanges();
```

Snippet 2:

```
var client = database.Clients.Create();
client.Name = "Jonh Doe";
database.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: `Create()` creates a proxy for your `Client` POCO, but it is not attached to the database context.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679504(v=vs.113).aspx they don't.

"Note that this instance is NOT added or attached to the set"

So your second snippet should be

```
var client = database.Clients.Create();
client.Name = "Jonh Doe";
database.Clients.Add(client);
database.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: So why is the need to use the `Create()` method?

Comment: In the same documentation it says it returns a proxy if the type matches all the requirements.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know the meaning of "proxy" in this context.

Comment: Ask the EF team or read the documentation. I'm just the messenger.

Comment: I believe if it is a self tracking proxy and you add it to the set then it will be tracked by itself.